# Laravel Relationships / attributes to common linked table

Tags: php, laravel, models, controllers, relationships

Let me just start off by saying I'm VERY new to Laravel. 
I have a table for listbox items (truncated migration code below):

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('list_item');
$table->string('group');
$table->integer('sort_order')->default(1);
```

Group is used for e.g "TITLE", "SPECIALITIES" etc. 
I'm linking user_title_li_id (in the users table) to the id of this table, as well as 
provider_title_li_id, provider_speciality_li_id in the providers table etc

How do I set up the relationship in the User and List Item models, in order to get the list_item (e.g. Professor) for each Model in the controller?

Comment: isn't that the `migration`? not the model.. btw, dont forget to add [the foreign key constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). after that [add a relation on the model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships). oh right, laravel also had default naming convention that might be come handy for helping the framework to find the relationship.

Comment: "(truncated MIGRATION code below)"
So do I add the FK constraint to both tables I guess?

Comment: If I need to add the FKs on the Migration, it would need to look something like this: 
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('id')->references('user_title_li_id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('id')->references('provider_title_li_id')->on('providers');
    $table->foreign('id')->references('provider_speciality_li_id')->on('providers');
....
I'm not sure if this is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, define a function like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the list items for the user.
     */
    public function listItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ListItem', 'foreign_key', 'list_item');
    }
}
```